# Success callback not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting a weird issue that my `success` callback is not executing. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "script",
    cache: false,
    url: 'Scripts/XXXX.min.js',
    success: function () {
        alert('sad')
    }
})
```

Just found that error is executing. Here is it's value Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "/** ↵ * Klass.js - copyright @dedfat ↵ * XXXXXX); ↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: try putting `error` callback, might be possible its going there !

Comment: are your the there is no error thrown by the request? try the `error` callback

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX call is successful? Have you tried adding an `error` handler or checking the console for errors?

Comment: yes error is executing. Here is it's value Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "/** ↵ * Klass.js - copyright @dedfat ↵ * XXXXXX); ↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that there is was an error inside the file. That's why success callback not executed.

Answer (score 2):

So you can try to construct your ajax likes below with both error and success callbacks.

Try that.

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "script",
        cache: false,
        url: 'Scripts/XXXX.min.js',
        error: function(returnval) {
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (returnval) {
           alert('success'); 
        }
    })
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: @user960567 could you put that edit on {code block} for clarity ?

Comment: I got the issue Thanks. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. When error You should see alert with error message. 
You can also chcek error in FireBug in network tab.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "script",
    cache: false,
    url: 'Scripts/XXXX.min.js',
    success: function() {
        alert('succes')

    }
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
})​
```